bijection between n and k letter alphabet
What is bijection between strings over n and k letter alphabet, k,n positive integers ?
I'm about to construct a bijection for sentences and binary strings, but I've failed .
Can I construct a bijection such that length of the sentence in MSL is non-decreasing ?
Can I characterize all the bijections ?

This is not (yet) a computer programming question. This appears to be a mathematics question: constructing a bijection between two sets, and classifying all possible bijections (Also, it's not clear what this has to do multiple single-level (MSL) security.)

@RaymondChen MSL is intended to be many sorted logic.
